# Shopify line items using webhook when order updated

Tags: php, xml, shopify

I am using shopify webhook to update my sql server's 'qty' field  when order updated, 
below is my php code

```
?php
$xmlData = fopen('php://input' , 'rb'); 
while (!feof($xmlData)) { $xmlString .= fread($xmlData, 4096); }
fclose($xmlData);
$xml = new SimplexmlElement($xmlString);


file_put_contents('orders/order' . '.xml', $xmlString);



$dom = new DomDocument();

$dom->load('orders/order.xml');

$itemList = $dom->getElementsByTagName('line-item');
foreach($itemList as $item) {
  $sku='';
  $qty='';
  foreach($item->childNodes as $child) {
    if ($child->localName == 'sku') {
      $sku = $child->textContent;
    }
    if ($child->localName == 'quantity') {
      $qty = $child->textContent;
    }
  }
  mysql_connect ("?????????????????????????");
mysql_select_db("??????????");

$query = "UPDATE xcart_categories SET product_count = product_count - $qty WHERE description='$sku';";

mysql_query($query);
}
```

and below is xml file i am getting from shopify webhook

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<order>
  <buyer-accepts-marketing type="boolean">true</buyer-accepts-marketing>
  <closed-at type="datetime" nil="true"></closed-at>
  <currency>USD</currency>
  <email>yeongju_l@yahoo.com</email>
  <financial-status>pending</financial-status>
  <fulfillment-status>fulfilled</fulfillment-status>
  <gateway>Local Pick-Up</gateway>
  <id type="integer">140303247</id>
  <name>#1012</name>
  <note></note>
  <number type="integer">12</number>
  <subtotal-price type="decimal">0.2</subtotal-price>
  <taxes-included type="boolean">false</taxes-included>
  <total-discounts type="decimal">0.0</total-discounts>
  <total-line-items-price type="decimal">0.2</total-line-items-price>
  <total-price type="decimal">0.2</total-price>
  <total-price-usd type="decimal">0.2</total-price-usd>
  <total-tax type="decimal">0.0</total-tax>
  <total-weight type="integer">0</total-weight>
  <updated-at type="datetime">2012-09-16T21:20:07-04:00</updated-at>
  <created-at type="datetime">2012-09-16T21:08:30-04:00</created-at>
  <token>dcf523d93c68159c15a7c8d1fabbee07</token>
  <landing-site>/products/test</landing-site>
  <referring-site></referring-site>
  <cancelled-at type="datetime" nil="true"></cancelled-at>
  <cancel-reason nil="true"></cancel-reason>
  <cart-token>a9a7bc5d8103f6a3bb45e827f0cb8928</cart-token>
  <browser-ip nil="true"></browser-ip>
  <landing-site-ref nil="true"></landing-site-ref>
  <order-number type="integer">1012</order-number>
  <discount-codes type="array"/>
  <note-attributes type="array">
  </note-attributes>
  <processing-method>manual</processing-method>
  <line-items type="array">
    <line-item>
      <id type="integer">228531213</id>
      <requires-shipping type="boolean">false</requires-shipping>
      <fulfillment-service>manual</fulfillment-service>
      <grams type="integer">0</grams>
      <price type="decimal">0.2</price>
      <quantity type="integer">1</quantity>
      <sku>1234567</sku>
      <title>test</title>
      <product-id type="integer">104663831</product-id>
      <variant-id type="integer">240660979</variant-id>
      <vendor>5 Second</vendor>
      <variant-title nil="true"></variant-title>
      <fulfillment-status>fulfilled</fulfillment-status>
      <name>test</name>
      <variant-inventory-management></variant-inventory-management>
      <properties type="array">
      </properties>
    </line-item>
  </line-items>
  <shipping-lines type="array"/>
  <tax-lines type="array">
    <tax-line>
      <title>NY State Tax</title>
      <price type="decimal">0.0</price>
      <rate type="float">0.04</rate>
    </tax-line>
    <tax-line>
      <title>Queens County Tax</title>
      <price type="decimal">0.0</price>
      <rate type="float">0.04875</rate>
    </tax-line>
  </tax-lines>
  <billing-address>
    <first-name>Yeongju</first-name>
    <last-name>Lee</last-name>
    <address1>14809 northern blvd</address1>
    <address2></address2>
    <city>Flushing</city>
    <company></company>
    <country>United States</country>
    <phone></phone>
    <province>New York</province>
    <zip>11354</zip>
    <latitude type="decimal">40.76529</latitude>
    <longitude type="decimal">-73.81831</longitude>
    <name>Yeongju Lee</name>
    <country-code>US</country-code>
    <province-code>NY</province-code>
  </billing-address>
  <fulfillments type="array">
    <fulfillment>
      <id type="integer">67712419</id>
      <order-id type="integer">140303247</order-id>
      <created-at type="datetime">2012-09-16T21:20:07-04:00</created-at>
      <updated-at type="datetime">2012-09-16T21:20:07-04:00</updated-at>
      <tracking-number nil="true"></tracking-number>
      <tracking-company nil="true"></tracking-company>
      <status>success</status>
      <service>manual</service>
      <tracking-url>http://www.google.com/search?q=</tracking-url>
      <receipt>
      </receipt>
      <line-items type="array">
        <line-item>
          <id type="integer">228531213</id>
          <requires-shipping type="boolean">false</requires-shipping>
          <fulfillment-service>manual</fulfillment-service>
          <grams type="integer">0</grams>
          <price type="decimal">0.2</price>
          <quantity type="integer">1</quantity>
          <sku>1234567</sku>
          <title>test</title>
          <product-id type="integer">104663831</product-id>
          <variant-id type="integer">240660979</variant-id>
          <vendor>5 Second</vendor>
          <variant-title nil="true"></variant-title>
          <fulfillment-status>fulfilled</fulfillment-status>
          <name>test</name>
          <variant-inventory-management></variant-inventory-management>
          <properties type="array">
          </properties>
        </line-item>
      </line-items>
    </fulfillment>
  </fulfillments>
  <customer>
    <id type="integer">96489088</id>
    <email>yeongju_l@yahoo.com</email>
    <accepts-marketing type="boolean">true</accepts-marketing>
    <first-name>Yeongju</first-name>
    <last-name>Lee</last-name>
    <orders-count type="integer">12</orders-count>
    <total-spent type="decimal">16.26</total-spent>
    <note nil="true"></note>
    <created-at type="datetime">2012-08-17T11:31:50-04:00</created-at>
    <updated-at type="datetime">2012-09-16T21:20:07-04:00</updated-at>
    <state>enabled</state>
    <last-order-id type="integer">140303509</last-order-id>
    <tags>C</tags>
    <last-order-name>#1013</last-order-name>
  </customer>
</order>
```

like you see i got two sku and qty because of duplicated line-item so for example when customer order one "product name - test in this case i got "-2" quantity update in my sql server sku test field , but  when i am  using webhook event when order creation it worked i mean i see only one line item but all the other cases(when order updated, when order payment, when order fullfillment..) show me duplicated line item even there is only one item ordered

anyone who got idea to fix this thing?
Thank you so much in advance guys......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're parsing your XML badly. You'll notice that one of the `line-items` tags is in the root of the response, while the other is nested under the `fulfillments` node. The former is a full listing of the line items for the order, and the latter is a record of the individual fulfillments made against the order (there might be several).

I'd find an XML parser and put it to work on the data so that you can access it in a structured fashion and only pull line items from the first `line-items` node.

Comment: Thanks David Can you teach me correct code to pull  'line items' from the first line-items node i will really appreciate it! Thanks..again..

Comment: Parsing XML in PHP is not something I'm too familiar with, but a quick Google search reveals that [SimpleXML](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) might be a good choice. Good luck!